# How to divide yield on parse function with multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to divide requests from lists.

```
first_list = ["https://www.url1.com", "https://www.url2.com"]
second_list = ["https://www.url3.com", "https://www.url4.com"]
third_list = ["https://www.url5.com", "https://www.url6.com"]

for url in first_list:
    yield Request(url=url, callback=self.my_function)

for url in second_list:
    yield Request(url=url, callback=self.my_function)

for url in third_list:
    yield Request(url=url, callback=self.my_function)
```

To put each list inside a process.

For example:

While the first url from first_list is being processed, the firsts urls from second_list and third_list to be processed too (at the same time). And so on.

**NOTE:** This is **NOT** Scrapy. It's a customized spider. It looks like Scrapy but isn't.

Comment: do you want to divide things up exactly like that?  i.e. three processes executing exactly two urls each.  `map` in `multiprocessing.Pool` can take care of arranging which tasks are run in which process and would simplify things a lot if you can use it

Comment: @SamMason - Yes, I know. But how to do that? I have tried in some ways but didn't worked. My last trying was like this:

![Valid XHTML](https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMypIhSg2u0gAhZm5cCanAKrIieRAmDHyS9rkyS).

![Valid XHTML](https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipPw1rt8wuL14qOlWP4kda9czTPZ8JmLDEzHqR_T).

![Valid XHTML](https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipPxrxXlNaUBkpHgjsElM_dQzmlQx0we7RPTtc06).

Comment: how to do what?  please edit the question to include relevant details, and don't post code as images, especially off-site images